# How to fill empty vertical space between header and footer

Tags: css

I have a header with a text and its padding; a footer, with a text and its padding too, and the content.
The content has a backgronud image, and text, with relative margins.
I want that the content fills the empty space between the footer and the header, so the page is full.
How can I do it?
Thanks!

Edit:
I have this code:

```
<header>
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
        <li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<main>
    <h1>hello</h1>
</main>

<footer>
    <h1>bye</h1>
</footer>
```

With js, I substract the height of footer and header to the window's height:

```
$('main').height($(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height());
```

But this is not exact, I still have a bit of vertical scroll.

Comment: You are going to have to add some code showing the effort you have put into accomplishing this on your own. After you show your current relevant code to this, then it will be much more likely for you to receive help.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, I've replaced the height() on the substract for outerHeight(true), and added "overflow: hidden" to the three elements (main, header, footer) to avoid the collapsing margin effects.